# Java code translation of Python array-splitting code

Tags: java, python

Can someone please give the Java equivalent of the below python (which slices a given array into given parts) which was originally written by ChristopheD here:

```
def split_list(alist, wanted_parts=1):
   length = len(alist)
   return [ alist[i*length // wanted_parts: (i+1)*length // wanted_parts] 
            for i in range(wanted_parts) ]
```

I don't know any python but can really use the above code in my Java app. Thanks

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
List<List<T>> splitList(List<T> alist, int wantedParts) {
    ArrayList<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    int length = alist.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < wantedParts; i++) {
        result.append(alist.subList(i*length/wantedParts,
                                    (i+1)*length/wantedParts));
    }

    return result;
}
```

If your `alist` will be structurally modified later in any way, you will have to make a copy of the sublist created by the `subList` method within the code, otherwise the results will be unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks for your code Tamas.

One problem though.

sublist returns a List<Integer> but when i try to declare  a List<Integer> it tells me "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>". it won't accept ArrayList<Integer> for result? What can i do there?

Comment: @techventure get a java compiler version 5 or later.

Comment: ok managed to get it working.

There's a problem with the code when the Lists isn't of even number size.

for example a list of 9 numbers, it only goes upto 8 .

Comment: Works great Tamas, but i can't see what changed to make it work, to me it seems like you only changed "single_list_length" to length/wantedPeaces which is the same thing?  Thank you for taking the time. much appreciated.

Comment: ok now i know - the rounding of the length/peaces division was causing the problem in your initial code :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, the google collections api has a function called partition which does precisely that